# Implementing asynchronous delays

Tags: c++, c, async-await

What would be a smart way to implement something like the following?

```cpp
// Plain C function for example purposes.
void sleep_async(delay_t delay, void (* callback)(void *), void * data);
```

That is, a means of asynchronously executing a callback after a delay. POSIX, for example, has a few functions that do something like this, but they are mostly for asynchronous I/O (see [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html) for what I mean). What interests me about those functions how they are executed "as if" on a new thread, according to that manual page, where an implementation may choose to spawn "a single thread...to receive all notifications". I am aware that some may nonetheless choose to spawn a whole thread for each of them, and that stuff like this may require support from the OS itself, so this is just an example.

I already have a couple of ways I could implement this (e.g. priority queue of events sorted by wake time on a timer loop, with no need to start a thread at all), but I am wondering whether there already exists smart[er] or [more] complete implementations of what I want to accomplish. For example, maybe implementations of `Task.Delay()` from C♯ (and coroutines like it in other language environments) do something smart in minimizing the amount of thread spawning for getting asynchronous delays.

Why am I looking for something like this? As implied by the title, I'm looking for something asynchronous. The above signature is just a simple C example to illustrate roughly what POSIX does. I am implementing some C++20 coroutines for use with `co_await` and friends, with thread pools and whatnot. Scheduling anything that would end up synchronously waiting on something is probably a bad idea, as it would prevent otherwise free threads from doing any work. Spawning [and potentially immediately detaching] a new thread just to add in an asynchronous delay doesn't seem like a very smart idea, either. My timer loop idea could be okay, but that implies needing a predefined timer granularity, and overhead from the priority queue.

**Edit**

I neglected to mention any real set of target platforms, as a commenter mentioned. I don't expect to target anything outside the "usual" desktop platforms, so the quirks of embedded development are ignored. The way I plan to use asynchronous delays *themselves* this way does not necessarily require threading support (everything could just be on a timer loop), but threading will nonetheless be required and used in accord (namely thread pools on which coroutines would be scheduled).

Comment: I'm going to say no, there doesn't exist any platform-independent equivalent of your function.  The C language doesn't have any standard support for threading or multi-tasking, which immediately says "no" to platform independency.  The C++ language has support for threads.  With C, you'll need platform dependent threading support or if your lucky, your OS can support POSIX.

Comment: BTW, there are platforms that don't support threading.  So there's another point supporting "no" on platform-independency.  You may want to edit your post, listing the platform(s) you are targeting.  Remember, there is a whole world of embedded systems out there which are not Windows and not Linux.

Comment: I use `libevent` for such things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple but inefficient way would be to spawn a thread, have it sleep for `delay`, and then call the callback. This can be done in just a few lines using [`std::async()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

```
auto delayed_call = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
    callback(data);
});
```

As mentioned by Thomas Matthews, this requires support for threads. While it's fine for a one-off call, it's not efficient if you have many such delayed calls. Having a priority queue and an event loop or a dedicated thread to handle events in this queue, as you already mentioned, is probably the most efficient way to do it. If you are looking for a library that implements this, then have a look at [`boost::asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).

As for using C++20 coroutines, I do not think that this will make something like your `sleep_async()` any easier. However, an event loop could be implemented on top of it.

Comment: I meant to use something like the example `sleep_async` to make coroutined async sleeping easier, not the other way around. But, if you think my event loop idea would be good enough, I suppose I can use that. I did something quite close to your example in testing out different approaches, but, as you said, probably not a good idea for many such calls.

Answer (score 0):

A smart way? You mean really, really smart? That would be my own [implementation](https://github.com/user1095108/cr2/blob/master/coroutine.hpp), of course. You know about POSIX timers, you probably know about linux timers and the various hacks involving `std::thread`. But, more seriously, what you require sounds mostly to the tune of something like [libeio](http://cvs.schmorp.de/libeio/eio.h), or [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/) - both of these provide callbacks. It depends on what you can afford in binary size and whether you like the particular abstractions a library offers. The 2 libraries seem to be evolved versions of [libevent](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/) and [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), `libevent` being the progenitor of them all.

Creating a `std::thread` instance involves allocating a stack frame, at the very least, which is by no means cheap.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is using C++20 coroutines. C# Task.Delay function delays the current job (coroutine) using the same thread. C++ coroutines does the same.

You could see an example of delays using C++20 coroutines here

[C++ delay example with coroutines](https://github.com/JoseManuelVargas/cpp-coroutines/blob/main/samples/delay_example.cpp)